# Can I both map to Observables, that are piped into mergeMap -> forkJoin AND pass an object to the downstream in RxJs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I know, it's a rather complicated question, but I'm very much lost in the RxJs documentation ...

I have an Angular application, and I'm using the OpenLibrary API for creating a homework assignment. I have a service, called `SearchService`, that uses the `/search` endpoint. The problem is that this endpoint returns documents that are not in the desirable format, so for each returned document I have to query the actual object from a different endpoint, one-by-one, as batch querying seems to be impossible currently (server just returns `HTTP 500`).

My solution, that's currently working is as follows:

1. Query the `/search` endpoint using Angular's `HttpClient`, this function returns an `Observable<AuthorSearchResponse>`
2. Pipe this into an RxJs `map` operator, filter out bad values, and map the result documents (each of them) to an `Observable<Author>`, that is produced by another service (`this.authorService.getAuthorById(id)` also uses `HttpClient` to query and transform a given author by ID)
3. Pipe this `Observable<Author>[]` into a `mergeMap` RxJs operator, that uses the `forkJoin` operator. This will produce the desired `Author[]` array
4. Pipe this result into a `map` operator, that transforms this array into the desirable `QueryResult<Author>` object, that contains an array of `Author`s, as well as the current number of items returned, and it *should* contain the total number of search results.

This is what my code looks like:

### The `AuthorSearchResponse` interface

```js
interface AuthorSearchResponse {
  start: number;
  numFound: number;
  docs: {
    type: string;
    key: string;
  }[];
}
```

### The `QueryResult<T>` interface

```js
export interface QueryResult<T> {
  totalCount: number;
  count: number;
  data: T[];
}
```

### My function

```js
// This whole thing produces a QueryResult<Author> instance
return this.httpClient
      .get<AuthorSearchResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/search/authors.json`, {
        params: params,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((searchResponse) =>
          searchResponse.docs
            .filter(
              (doc) => doc.type === 'author' && typeof doc.key !== 'undefined'
            )
            .map((doc) =>
              // getAuthorById returns Observable<Author>
              this.authorService.getAuthorById(correctAuthorKey(doc.key))
            )
        )
      )
      .pipe(mergeMap((o) => forkJoin(o)))
      .pipe(
        map((authors) => ({
          data: authors,
          totalCount: -1,
          count: authors.length,
        }))
      );
```

My **problem** is that currently I have no way of passing the `searchResponse` object to the final operator, which I would very much need to set the `totalCount` property in the final mapping. Is there any way in RxJs, to take both the `searchResponse` **AND** the `Observable<Author>[]` array produced in the first `map` operator, and when the `forkJoin` is finished (all `Author`s are loaded, and the `QueryResult` can be produced), use the `searchResponse` and the produced `Author[]` in the downstream to combine them into one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to nest your pipe by piping the `forkJoin` and use the `mergeMap` before the `map`:

```
return this.httpClient.get<AuthorSearchResponse>(
  `${environment.apiUrl}/search/authors.json`,
  { params: params }
).pipe(
  mergeMap((searchReponse) => forkJoin(searchReponse.docs
    .filter((doc) => doc.type === 'author' && doc.key != null)
    .map((doc) => this.authorService.getAuthorById(correctAuthorKey(doc.key)))
  ).pipe(
    map((authors) => ({
      data: authors,
      totalCount: searchReponse.numFound,
      count: authors.length,
    }))
  ))
);
```